# ZF2 / use 2 differents view helpers with the same name

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In a ZF2 modular application, I have 2 differents view helpers with the same name in 2 differents modules.

I want to use one in the first module, and the other one in the second module.

In the first module configuration file, I have a `view_helpers` config key with my view helpers definitions.

```
view_helpers => [
    myCustomViewHelper => myCustomViewHelper::class
]
```

In the second one,  I have a `my_module_view_helpers` config key ...

```
my_module_view_helpers => [
    myCustomViewHelper => myCustomViewHelper2::class
]
```

What I want to do, is to erase the first one by the second one for the second module.

How is it possible to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

I understood that Module load order determines which gets actually registered.  If you load your custom module last, it should become the defacto helper with that name.

Make sure to use the right keys in both module configs.

```
'view_helpers' => [
    'invokables' => [
        'thatHelper' => ThatHelper::class,
    ],
    'factories' => [
        'otherHelper' => ThatOtherHelper::class,
    ]
]
```

What you'll run into though, is any program reference to that helper in 'other' modules will also use yours.  Unless that's the intention, that could cause a world of hurt.  My advice, give it a new name. ;)  It's just a name! :D

Comment: thanks for your answer, I know how it works but in my case, I don't want to have `myCustomViewHelper` in one module and `myCustomViewHelper2` (or other) in the other one. I know it's just a name but ...  ;)

Comment: No probs, Did you give what I suggested a shot?  Same name, load your module after the "other one" in your application.config.php

Comment: Yes but if I load the second module before the first, my first helper will be erased, and I want to use it in my first module

Comment: All view helpers are registered with the same manager.  I don't know that you can achieve the behavior you want, short of wiring your helper to react to some rule.  You can get the template, from your helper, like this for example:  `/** @var PhpRenderer $engine */
     $engine = $this->getView()->getEngine();
     echo $engine->viewModel()->getRoot()->getChildren()[0]->getTemplate();`

Comment: @ceadreak There is no modules in zf2 application. Only one single application.